# How to remove wrong schema from an URL (with PHP)

Tags: php

I need to remove a wrong schema from an URL submitted as a string.

I start with this consideration:

**The only two allowed schemas are `http://` and `https://`**

Starting from this consideration, I need to remove from the `string` all wrongly formatted schemas like:

- `htp://example.com`
- `htps://example.com`
- `http:/example.com`
- `https:/example.com`
- `htpexample.com`
- `htps://example.com`
- `http:/example.com`
- `https:/example.com`
- ... many many more ...

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to calculate all possible variation of wrong schemas?
2. Which is the best approach to remove them from the given `string`?

**ABOUT QUESTION 2**

My first approach would be to create an array with all the wrong schemas and then use something like this:

```
$wrongSchemas = [/* here all the possible wrong schemas calculated from question 1 */];
$url = str_replace($wrongSchemas, '', $url);
```

But this approach relies on a correct order, because instead I risk to remove partial schemas and make it wrong anyway.

And anyway I need to find a way to create the array `$wrongSchemas`!

Any suggestion or any further consideration on the topic that I'm missing, is well appreciated.

Comment: 'htpexample.com' there is no way to extract the wrong schema from this. Maybe the intended url is http://pexemple.com. You have no way to know.

Comment: It's quite esay, as shwon in the answers below, to filter the urls with the right schemas. But to correct the wrong ones would only be guessing, even manually.

Comment: Yes, I need to guess... If the schema is present and is correct, OK; if the schema is not present at all, ok. But what I need to guess if a schema is present BUT is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

use `strpos` check in your `$url`

```
if(strpos($url,"http://")!==0 && strpos($url,"https://")!==0){
    //wrong schemas
    $exp_string = "";
    // $exp_string = strpos($url,"//")?"//":"/";
    if(strpos($url,"://"))
        $exp_string = "://";
    elseif(strpos($url,":/"))
        $exp_string = ":/";
    elseif(strpos($url,":"))
        $exp_string = ":";
    elseif(strpos($url,"//"))
        $exp_string = "//";
    $temp = explode($exp_string,$url);
    if(count($temp)>1){
        $url = '';
        for($i=1;$i<count($temp);$i++){
            $url = $url.$temp[$i];
        }
        //if needed you can add http:// here: $url = 'http://'.$url;
    }
}
echo $url;
//process for right schemas
```

If you need more validations like url starting with ht,htp,etc you can use **checkdnsrr** or **gethostbyname** functions to validate domains

Comment: This is not correct: this tells me if it is correct or not, but I don't need to know if it is correct or not. I need to remove the schema if it is in the wrong form.

Comment: Without trying it, it seems it leaves out a wrong url like http:example.com

Comment: Does this deal also with wrong `htp`, `ht`, ecc... ? I know is not so simple that it will happen that a user will enter an URL with such a scheme, but I have to deal with a really "stupid" users!

Comment: then you should validate the domain name with **checkdnsrr** or **gethostbyname** functions. because domain names can start with htp or ht too.

Comment: No, I used the wrong words... I meant urla like htp:/example.com

Comment: yup the answer above will fix it

Answer (score 0):

I would search for :// if exists in string, after a then a simple in_array with the substring

```
$url="https://www.example.com";
$validschemas=array("http","https");
$pos=strpos($url,"://");
if($pos)
{
    $valid=in_array(substr($url,0,$pos),$validschemas)?true:false;
    //If not valid schema, remove schema from url, if it os ok dont touch it.
    if(!$valid)
       $url=substr($url,$pos+3);
}
else 
{
    //No schema, then url continues being the same
}
```

Comment: This is not correct: this tells me if it is correct or not, but I don't need to know if it is correct or not. I need to remove the schema if it is in the wrong form.

Comment: very easy, since you have the variable $pos just remove it after. I'm going to change my code. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

After some more thoughts, thanks also to some of your comments (thank you @Frédéric Clausset), I decided that the best approach would be to build the array of wrong schemas on the fly:

```
$schemas = ['http', 'htp', 'htt', 'ht', 'hp', 'ttp', 'tp'];
$delimiters = ['://', ':/', ':', '//', '/'];

$wrongCombinations = [];
foreach ($schemas as $wrongSchema) {
    foreach ($delimiters as $wrongDelimiter) {
        $combination = $wrongSchema . $wrongDelimiter;
        $combinationSecure = $wrongSchema . 's' . $wrongDelimiter;

        if ('http://' !== $combination) {
            $wrongCombinations[] = $combination;
        }

        if ('https://' !== $combinationSecure) {
            $wrongCombinations[] = $combinationSecure;
        }
    }
}
```

This generates a long array like this:

```
array:68 [▼
  0 => "http:/"
  1 => "https:/"
  2 => "http:"
  3 => "https:"
  4 => "http//"
  5 => "https//"
  6 => "http/"
  7 => "https/"
  8 => "htp://"
  9 => "htps://"
  10 => "htp:/"
  11 => "htps:/"
  12 => "htp:"
  13 => "htps:"
  14 => "htp//"
  15 => "htps//"
  16 => "htp/"
  17 => "htps/"
  18 => "htt://"
  19 => "htts://"
  20 => "htt:/"
  21 => "htts:/"
  22 => "htt:"
  23 => "htts:"
  24 => "htt//"
  25 => "htts//"
  26 => "htt/"
  27 => "htts/"
  28 => "ht://"
  29 => "hts://"
  30 => "ht:/"
  31 => "hts:/"
  32 => "ht:"
  33 => "hts:"
  34 => "ht//"
  35 => "hts//"
  36 => "ht/"
  37 => "hts/"
  38 => "hp://"
  39 => "hps://"
  40 => "hp:/"
  41 => "hps:/"
  42 => "hp:"
  43 => "hps:"
  44 => "hp//"
  45 => "hps//"
  46 => "hp/"
  47 => "hps/"
  48 => "ttp://"
  49 => "ttps://"
  50 => "ttp:/"
  51 => "ttps:/"
  52 => "ttp:"
  53 => "ttps:"
  54 => "ttp//"
  55 => "ttps//"
  56 => "ttp/"
  57 => "ttps/"
  58 => "tp://"
  59 => "tps://"
  60 => "tp:/"
  61 => "tps:/"
  62 => "tp:"
  63 => "tps:"
  64 => "tp//"
  65 => "tps//"
  66 => "tp/"
  67 => "tps/"
]
```

Those 68 combinations are all the possible wrong ones.

Now, a simple `str_replace` removes the schema if it is one of the wrong ones:

```
str_replace($combinations, '', $domain);
```

This intercept wrong URLs like:

- htp://example.com > example.com
- http:/example.com > example.com
- htps:/example.com > example.com
- hps:/example.com > example.com
- htp:example.com > example.com
- many many more
- all possible variations

Thank you to all of you for your answers that helped me to better clarify the problem and find my solution! :)

PS
If you find bugs or drawbacks in this code, please, let me know!